# How to use CASE together with date INTERVAL?

Tags: sql, mysql, case

I want to have this query:

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE('2010-09-10'), (CASE DATETYPE WHEN 'H' THEN INTERVAL 1 WEEK ELSE INTERVAL 1 YEAR END CASE))) AS wdt
```

MySQL says it's invalid

also I have tried

```
 SELECT _DATE AS wdt 
 UNION ALL 
 CASE DATETYPE
        WHEN 'H' THEN SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(_DATE, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AS wdt ;
        ELSE SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(DATE('2010-09-10'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK )) AS wdt;
  END CASE;
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(_DATE, INTERVAL 2 WEEK)) AS wdt
```

which doesn't work also, error in query syntax.

How can I select interval 1 year for dates that are Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two DATE_SUB operations would work:

```
SELECT IF (DATETYPE  = 'H', 
           DATE_SUB(DATE('2010-09-10'), INTERVAL 1 WEEK),
           DATE_SUB(DATE('2010-09-10'), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
       as wdt;
```